# unable to connect to api via node proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

i've been trying to connect to an external api natively with my react component but CORS was blocking the response. so i decided to create a backend node proxy which doesnt work and keep getting the same error, cross-origin request blocked.

node server code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors({
    allowedHeaders: ['Authorization', 'Content-Type'],
    credentials: true
}));

app.get('/user', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://demo.xxxxx.com/api/v2/user', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxx' 
            }, 
        });
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.send(response.data)
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

React Code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import data from './templates.json';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

function Dashboard() {
    console.log(data)

    async function handleOnClick(){
        try {

            const response = await axios.get("https://localhost:3001/user", {
               
            })
            console.log(response)
        }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
    }
    }
        
  return (
      <>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>Hello</Button>
      </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

can anyone help identify what the issue is, please?

Comment: ps - im using firefox

Comment: Maybe it's the external API that doesnt allow you to connect from any origin?

Comment: No can’t be, it’s a fully supported api for external access

Comment: You  need to allow your client Web origin in your server's CORS configuration.

Comment: During coding and debugging on your localhost you could get rid of the cors configuration with a cors browser plugin such as CORS Everywhere for Firefox. But be aware that you are using this tool only during your development.

Comment: ive tried using the cors everywhere plugin for ff, still to no avail